# libgdx and android application. Image as background

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am new and I just start my journey with libgdx. I would like to know how I can do image.png in resolution 960x640 as background in my game? This is possible? Thx for advices and forbearance. Maybe you hava a simply tutorial?
This is my render class:

```
public void render() {

     texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("E:/background.png"));

     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
     batch.begin();
     batch.draw(texture, 0, 0);
     batch.end();
}
```

Second question. I need to insert two active images, active means when I click on that image, the next image show me on the screen. I want to implement action when I click on that picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your create() method, create a new Texture referencing your image.png, and then use your existing SpriteBatch to render it in the render() loop. Immediately after your GL.clear() call, go your batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0. 0) and make sure you're in OrthographicProjection mode for your camera.

Comment: I get error: Texture width and height must be powers of two: 960x640

Comment: You can get around this by overriding the power of 2 check in the Texture class. At the beginning of your main create() method, add this:

`Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);`

Comment: I've not seen any performance or compatibility impacts. I suspect that it may be an issue on older devices that have older GPUs with only OpenGL 1.0 support. I'm not entirely sure, I haven't tested it on a device that it did not work...

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set the view port
do this in your create method

`float scrw = 960;
        float scrh = 640;

```
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.viewportHeight = scrh;
    camera.viewportWidth = scrw;

    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .5f,
            camera.viewportHeight * .5f, 0f);
    camera.update();`
```

create a texture

`texture = new Texture("data/background.png");`

put this texture in a sprite like this

`sprite=new sprite(texture);`

and then set the size like this

`sprite.setsize(960,640);`

and draw it in your render methods between batch.begin
and batch.end

`sprite.draw(batch);`